# How to clear database field after user inactivity, logout or session end

Tags: php, session, laravel, paypal

I have a pivot table that is holding `shopping cart` type information like so [image]

I set `processing= true` while I am getting payment information and count them along with the `registered` ones so inventory does not get oversold by simultaneous purchases. I can set `processing=false` if payment fails.

However in the cases where I don't get to finish payment processing...How do I reset `processing` to false when the user logs out, times out  or ends their session or any other cases?

Comment: capture that session in any variable. And, whenever you are calling for session timeout or whenever user ending their session.. use that variable in sql query to make processing false.

Comment: Logout is a possitive event, so you can capture that, but timeout is not a positive event. You have to write a cron for example, that runs every `session_timeout+X` that cleans up all dropped sessions and returns inventory

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the user activity you could do all of the following:

1. Set SESSION variable and keep track of the time, if time expires then set the value to false
2. When user disconnects set value to false
3. Depending on the database you are using you could add a timed event to set the value to false.

   - For postgresql see [pgAgent](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/dev/pgagent.html)
   - For mysql see [Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-overview.html)

Comment: Point 1. will not work, either the session is active, or session data is lost, see @RiggsFolly's comment above. Even if you use a timeout that is shorter than session timeout, you cannot be sure that there will be another request happening within session timeout. Please correct.

Comment: However, you could use JavaScript to call back the server at a defined time; the JavaScript can also carry the sessionID or any other ID by itself. But that will not work, if JavaScript is not enabled, and therefore should not be used in payment environments, or only if you rule out payment completely when JavaScript is not enabled.

Comment: I think 2. and 3. together would be a good solution to this problem for most cases. I'm going to give it a try.

Comment: you are right that "Point 1" will not work at its own. That's why I said "all of the following" and not "any"!
In fact Point 3 supersedes all other points and it is the most reliable.